# counting the number of occurrences of any word from text file

Tags: bash

i'm tring to write a script that priting the number of occurrences that each word appear, using commands like grep, find, sort and more..

the problem is that every sign that is not a-z A-Z 0-9 in the text should be treated as a space

for example:

```
it's not what i mention@ed to do to to
```

should be read like

```
it s not what i mention ed to do to to
```

so the script should print:

```
1 do
1 ed
1 i
1 it
1 mention
1 not
1 s
1 what
3 to
```

sorting first by the number of occurrences after that by alphabeit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sequence should do it:

```
$ echo "it's not what i mention@ed to do to to" | \
      tr -C '[:alnum:]' '[\n*]' | grep . | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
  1 do
  1 ed
  1 i
  1 it
  1 mention
  1 not
  1 s
  1 what
  3 to
```

- Replace non-alphanumeric with newline
- Filter non-blank lines
- Sort (for uniq)
- Count unique
- Sort by count